# Creating intervals in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, categorical-data

## List item

I am new to programming so don't know much about it.

I have a dataset like this:-

```
Type    Value

A        40

A        70     

A        125

A        150

B        50

B        80

B        130

B        150
```

And I want in this format:

```
Type  <60  >60  >90  >120

A      1    3    2    2

B      1    3    2    2
```

Basically, count and categorize the values.

```
def delay_tag(list_name):
    empty_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(airline)): 
        if list_name[i] < 60:
             empty_list.append('<60') 
        elif (list_name[i] > 60):
            empty_list.append('>60') 
        elif (list_name[i] >= 120):
            empty_list.append('>120')
        else:
             empty_list.append('>= 180')
        return(empty_list)
```

This is what I Tried

Comment: There is only one way to no longer be new at programming: it's to actually program yourself.

Comment: That I know, I have been programming but I don't know how to do this step.

Comment: If you have no clue, then read tutorials, if you have made an honest attempt, then show your code.

Comment: def delay_tag(list_name):
    empty_list= []
    for i in range(0,len(airline)):
        if list_name[i] < 60:
            empty_list.append('<60')
        elif (list_name[i] > 60):
            empty_list.append('>60')
        elif (list_name[i] >= 120):
            empty_list.append('>120')
       else:
            empty_list.append('>= 180')
    return(empty_list)

Comment: edit your post and format your code rather than stuffing it into an unreadable comment please...

Answer (score 0):

This may give you an idea.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Type':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
        'Value':[40,70,125,150,50,80,130,150]
    })
df_lt60 = df[df['Value']<60]
print df_lt60.groupby('Type').Value.nunique()

df_gt60 = df[df['Value']>=60]
print df_gt60.groupby('Type').Value.nunique()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read.csv('your_file.csv')

fun = lambda x:{'<60':x.lt(60).sum(),'>60':x.gt(60).sum(),'>90':x.gt(90).sum(),'>120':x.gt(120).sum()}

pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Type').Value.apply(fun)).reset_index().pivot('Type','level_1','Value')

Out[76]: 
level_1  <60  >120  >60  >90
Type                        
A          1     2    3    2
B          1     2    3    2
```